# Django Redirect Urls.py errors

Tags: python, django, forms, url, redirect

I would like to create a registration form, which then sends more data to another form. My user chooses his username and password on the first form that redirect to the second form where he fills in information such as his city, favorite sport...etc. These two steps work perfectly on their own.
Only then I would like to send on a third form on which the user fills in the data of his dogs, which is in another app. For this I use the urls.py of the project, and I include the urls.py of the apps. From there it no longer works.
If I only use the users form, and its urls, it works, but if I import the urls.py then I cannot access the second form without a "NoReverseMatch at /signup/
Reverse for 'additional_details_main_user' not found. 'additional_details_main_user' is not a valid view function or pattern name.NoReverseMatch at /signup/." This error happens after the first form, which is only username and password. I cannot even access to the other one of the user.

This is my code structure:

1. robert (main app)

   - urls.py
2. userProfile

- folders : templates, static...etc
- urls.py

3. dogProfile

- folders : templates, static...etc
- urls.py

**urls.py from robert:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('userProfile.urls')), 
    path('', include('dateProfile.urls')), 
]
```

**APP USERPROFILE :**
**views.py from userProfile :**

```
`from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from userProfile.forms import MainUserSignUpForm, DetailsMainUserForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from userProfile.models import DetailsMainUser

def signup_main_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MainUserSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('additional_details_main_user')
    else:
        form = MainUserSignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'userProfile/signup.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def additional_details_main_user(request):
    user_profile, created = DetailsMainUser.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DetailsMainUserForm(request.POST, instance=user_profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('targetedProfileRegister')
    else:
        form = DetailsMainUserForm(instance=user_profile)
    return render(request, 'userProfile/additional_details_main_user.html', {'form': form})
`
```

**signup.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
    <p class="text-center">If you already have an account, <a href="/login">login</a> instead.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from userProfile import views

app_name = 'userProfile'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup_main_user, name='signup'),
    path('signup/additional_details_main_user/', views.additional_details_main_user, name='additional_details_main_user'), 
]
```

It does work if I don't use the urls.py from userProfile but only use urls.py from robert like this :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('signup/', views.signup_main_user, name='signup'),
    path('additional_details_main_user/', views.additional_details_main_user, name='additional_details_main_user'),
```

But I cannot use it that way as I will have many apps.

Thanks in advance for your help ! It's my first Django App :)

I tried adding a  in my template but then I had "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." error. Also, following different online videos, it does not seem that the {% url %} should be necessary.

I also tried to change the redirect fields.

Comment: FIXED !!
I changed my urls.py from main project to : path('signup/', include('userProfile.urls')), 
And then in subprojects : path('', views.signup_main_user, name='signup'),
    path('additional_details_main_user/', views.additional_details_main_user, name='additional_details_main_user'), 
So basically took of the "signup" from the subproject and added to the main one. Then in my views I changed the redirect to : return redirect('userProfile:additional_details_main_user')